# DenoでWebsocketを使った際のヘッダにOriginを含めたい（Node.jsのように）

Tags: javascript, websocket, deno

I am currently trying to make a websocket connection from local with Deno's WebSocket Client.
but, no includes Origin in Header.
現在、DenoのWebSocket Clientを使ってローカルからWebSocket接続を行おうとしています。
しかし、ヘッダにOriginが含まれていません。

I would expect the Header to include the Origin portion.
ヘッダーにはOriginの部分が含まれることを期待しています。

```
new WebSocket("wss://localhost");

// no includes Origin in Header
```

Comment: 当サイトは日本語でのやり取りをメインにしているので、英語の併記は不要です。 / 英語でのやり取りを希望する場合には https://stackoverflow.com に投稿する必要があります。